# iOS - If app has launched for the first time - Presenting ModalView

Tags: ios, storyboard

I figured out how to present two differnt view controllers at the time of app launch and it works fine if I dont present them modally. somehow it shows blank view controller if I change code.
From ->     self.window.rootViewController = landingVC;
To->        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:landingVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Here's the complete code in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *tabbarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarViewController"];
UIViewController *landingVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandingViewController"];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {

        self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
 } else {
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:landingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
      }

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

AFAIK, thats how modalVC should be shown. I've already verified storyboardIDs and checked "use storyboardIDs" for both viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is setting the root view controller as the tabbarController if the app has been launched before, otherwise you're telling the app's root view controller (which hasn't been set and doesn't exist yet) to present the view controller.

I would be willing to guess that if you put NSLog(@"%@", self.window.rootViewController); above the presentViewController line, you would get back nil, meaning you're trying to tell nil to do something, which of course won't work.

I just tried this and it works:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIViewController *testRootVC = [UIViewController new];
    testRootVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.window.rootViewController = testRootVC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (YES) {
        UIViewController *testModalVC = [UIViewController new];
        testModalVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [testRootVC presentViewController:testModalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I agree and kinda guessed it.however i am not sure if making the tabbarVC the rootview first and then presenting the modalview will help. any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the edit I just made. What you want to do, it seems, is set the tabbar controller as the root view, tell the window to makeKeyAndVisible, THEN present the modal if this is the first launch. Try that out and let me know.

Comment: Weird. Its not working for me. Some debugging should fix it. thanks. Btw Are you on "B License"? looks like you've mastered the tunnel :)

Comment: Never heard of it... What is it?

Comment: I meant Skydiving license.

Comment: Oh! Nope, I'm just a tunnel flyer. :)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any more questions or need help debugging, we can go into chat if you want. I have a meeting in 2 minutes but should be available in about 20. Also, if this ends up helping a vote/accept of the answer would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes as you mentioned (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksdqvgf3i45i7ky/Screenshot%202014-08-21%2013.30.52.png). its showing tabbar in either condition. I put a breakpoint in condition block. it enters the block but still shows tabbar.

Comment: I had the same problem initially. You may have missed my comment about this, but you need to makeKeyAndVisible AFTER setting the rootViewController but BEFORE presenting the modal.